# Bug IEEEtran.bst file?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am about to submit my thesis and just realised that in the IEEEtran.bst file might be a bug.
The following 3 references are from my thesis:

```
[22] D. C. Henderson, “Weight gain with atypical antipsychotics: evidence and insights,” The 
Journal of clinical psychiatry. Supplement, vol. 68, no. 12, pp. 18–26, 2007.

[23] G. J. Marek, B. Behl, A. Y. Bespalov, G. Gross, Y. Lee, and H. Schoemaker, “Glutamatergic 
(n-methyl-d-aspartate receptor) hypofrontality in schizophrenia: too little juice or a miswired
brain?” Molecular pharmacology, vol. 77, no. 3, pp. 317–326, 2010.

[24] A. K. Malhotra, D. A. Pinals, H. Weingartner, K. Sirocco, C. David Missar, D. Pickar, and 
A. Breier, “Nmda receptor function and human cognition: the effects of ketamine in healthy 
volunteers,” Neuropsychopharmacology, vol. 14, no. 5, pp. 301–307, 1996.
```

You will notify that IEEEtran always puts a comma after the title apart from where there is a ?. I use bibtex and bibdesk and the comma after the title is there in all cases and I checked about 30 references in bibdesk and there's no comma after the title...

Any ideas how I can quickly fix that??

Comment: Can you also include these `.bib` entries and a simple document where cites only these three using the same class with your thesis?

Comment: I believe this is a precise choice made by the bib style authors: they want the punctuation before the closing quotes, so the question mark followed by a comma is out of the question.

Comment: As @egreg says, this is deliberate and is in the IEEE instructions to authors.

Comment: Hi, ok it seems it's not a bug but wanted by the authors. However, I do not quite follow what you were trying to say @egreg. I cannot see how there could be any confusion?? sorry. For example... "this is the title bla bla?", where is the confusion here?

Comment: The style wants the comma *before* the quotes; so for uniformity you'd get `“What is the name of this book?,”`

Comment: yes, but why is that useful?? why not "What is the name of this book?", Does not seem very straight forward to me, honestly :)

Comment: Ask the people who want the comma inside the quotes and not outside, which is more logical as the comma doesn't belong to the title.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is a precise choice made by the `bib` style authors: they want the punctuation before the closing quotes, so the question mark followed by a comma is out of the question.

Concerning quotes, there are two conventions:

1. If punctuation belongs to the quoted text, then it goes before the closing quotes, otherwise it goes after; in this case you'd have

   > “Weight gain with atypical antipsychotics: evidence and insights”, The 
   >   Journal of Clinical Psychiatry …
   >
   > “Glutamatergic (n-methyl-d-aspartate receptor) hypofrontality in schizophrenia: too little juice or a miswired brain?”, Molecular Pharmacology …
2. Punctuation *always* goes before the closing quote, as the Chicago Manual of Style, for instance, tells; in this case it must be

   > “Weight gain with atypical antipsychotics: evidence and insights,” The 
   >   Journal of Clinical Psychiatry …
   >
   > “Glutamatergic (n-methyl-d-aspartate receptor) hypofrontality in schizophrenia: too little juice or a miswired brain?” Molecular Pharmacology …

   with no comma in the second item because there's already a punctuation sign.

Apparently, the IEEEtran style follows the second convention. I'd follow the first one, which is more logical, but IEEE doesn't agree with you and me. When in Rome…

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I was banging my head against walls trying to fix this Chicago style...